# iOS warning: Implicit declaration of function 'pathInDocumentDirectory'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, warnings

I'm getting an "**Implicit declaration of function 'pathInDocumentDirectory'**" warning for this line of code while trying to develop my first iPhone app:

```
NSString *imagePath = pathInDocumentDirectory(s);
```

Strangely, I can't find any good information on what to do about this. Does anyone know how to get rid of the warning? Thanks!

Comment: Have you written pathInDocumentDirectory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is an inline function, move the declaration to the top of the implementation file (before anything uses it).

If it's a method you've written it should be an objective-c method...

```
-(NSString *)pathInDocumentDirectory:(NSString *)value {

}
```

Then you use...

```
NSString *path = [self pathInDocumentsDirectory:aValue];
```

Don't forget to declare the method in either the header or a private category in the implementation file.

Comment: Thanks Simon! In fact the mistake was even more basic than that: I'd forgotten an #import! Your answer made me realize that though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have import or include the header file which contains pathInDocumentDirectory function.
OR
If pathInDocumentDirectory function is in the same file ,just put it before the function where you used.Or just declare the pathInDocumentDirectory at first。